# How to pass variable name, but not its value into /var function as argument piece?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

I'm trying to divide a pipeline. Most of the parameters passed successful, but those containing variables are resolved before i need.

Jenkins ver. 2.164.1

```
Jenkins.file content:

stage ('prebuild') {
 steps {
  script {
   VERSION="temprorary-value"
   POSTBUILDACTION="make.exe \\some\\path\\file_${VERSION}"
  }
 }
}
stage ('build') {
 steps {
  script {
    build (POSTBUILDACTION) 
  }
 }
}

build.groovy content:
def call (String POSTBUILDACTION) {
     ...
     checkout somefile
     VERSION=readFile(somefile)
     bat "${POSTBUILDACTION}"
```

}

here i expected that version will be taken from redefined VERSION variable but POSTBUILDACTION passed into the function as a string. In result it's called as is ("make.exe \some\path\file_temprorary-value"). In fact command i'd like to get is (somefile contains only one number, for example "5")

```
make.exe \some\path\file_5
```

But now i have

```
make.exe \some\path\file_temprorary-value
```

Or if i trying to pass \${VERSION} like:

```
POSTBUILDACTION="make.exe \\some\\path\\file_\${VERSION}"
```

- it's transfer as is:

```
make.exe \some\path\file_${VERSION}
```

I've tried to view a class of POSTBUILDACTION in prebuild stage - it's equal "class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl" and same on build stage after passing throw - it become a string: "class java.lang.String"

So how to pass into a function argument contained a variable, but not it's value ?
OR
to "breathe life" into a dry string like

```
'make.exe \\some\\path\\file_${VERSION}'
```

so the variables could be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1 - lazy evaluation (`@NonCPS`)**

You can use a [GString with lazy evaluation](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_special_case_of_interpolating_closure_expressions), but since Jenkins doesn't serialize lazy `GString`s you'll have to return it from a `@NonCPS` method like so:

```
@NonCPS
def getPostBuildAction() {
    "make.exe \\some\\path\\file_${ -> VERSION }"
}

stage ('prebuild') {
    ...
}
```

Then you set `POSTBUILDACTION=getPostBuildAction()` and you can use `POSTBUILDACTION` as you wanted, but be aware that the object you have here is a `groovy.lang.GString` and not a `String`, so you'll want to change your parameter class (or simply use `def`.)

**Option 2 - use a closure for every call**

You can use an eager `GString` inside a closure:

```
def String getPostBuildAction() {
    "make.exe \\some\\path\\file_$VERSION"
}
```

But here you'll have to call `getPostBuildAction()` every time you want a different reading of `VERSION`, so you'll have to replace `POSTBUILDACTION` with this closure.